# How to delete duplicate records in Mysql where only 1 records will get deleted

Tags: mysql

I have tried sql for deleting duplicate record but this sql delete all records but I want to only one record and then all remaining records are deleted and this table contain only two columns and there is no primary key how to solve this problem.

Comment: If that's all you give, how do you expect as to help you?????  Before asking question, learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT duplicate records into a temporary table, DELETE records from source table, INSERT records from temporary table.

You should definitely backup your table/database before doing this.